# Ошибка MSB4019 при билде проекта на .net framework

Tags: c#, msbuild

Возникает ошибка при команде `dotnet clean` или `dotnet build` по всему `*.sln`. Как можно исправить?

```
error MSB4019: The imported project 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
was not found. 

Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сбилдить проект через UI в VS (или аналоге), команда `dotnet` работает только для .NET Core 3.1 и выше